# Formulário para sorteio

Tags: formulário, validação

Preciso de um formulário simples com campos para (nome e telefone). Abaixo uma lista com números de 1 a 100, por exemplo.

> O usuário preenche o form e após o "Submit" eu recebo um e-mail com as
>   informações e número escolhido pelo visitante. As mesmas informações
>   devem ser impressas na tela para o usuário.

Pois bem, até ai eu consigo fazer, só que eu preciso de algo mais. No caso **eu quero que o número escolhido pelo visitante 1 fique indisponível para o visitante 2 e assim sucessivamente**.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Grato desde já!

Comment: Isso precisa ser feito no servidor. Que servidor você está usando? E que linguagem de programação server-side?

Comment: Estou usando Apache e PHP

Comment: Na verdade eu nem quero que o sistema faça o sorteio, só quero que os números fiquem indisponíveis a medida que forem selecionados.

O sorteio eu farei de forma manual mesmo.

Comment: E como esta vinculando o cliente com o numero sorteado atualmente?

Comment: Estou enviando td para um banco de dados mysql.

Comment: Ué, então porque não utiliza esse banco pra verificar se o numero já não foi sorteado antes?

Comment: Pq não sei.

Peguei o código que faz a inserção no BD e imprime o resultado na tela, mas não sei como consultar o BD para o que preciso.

Comment: Acho que ai fica complicado, você sabe o que quer, você sabe o que tem, mas não tem a minima ideia de como fazer.... existem varias maneiras de realizar isso =(

Comment: Hahaha! Exatamente por isso pedi ajuda aqui. Lembrando que preciso verificar se o número já foi selecionado e não sorteado. Se eu já selecionei o 67 ele deve ficar indisponível para o próximo visitante e assim até o último número ser selecionado.

Comment: Veja bem, a rede SOpt não funciona exatamente dessa maneira, **quero fazer algo, façam pra mim**. O ideal é que tente algo, se surgir alguma duvida, ai sim fazer uma pergunta com um escopo fechado, do jeito que foi posta, eu votei pra fechar como ampla demais

Comment: Recomendo que faça um [tour] para conhecer melhor a comunidade SOpt e leia sobre [mcve]

Comment: Entendi. De qualquer forma obrigado!

Comment: Se esses numeros de 1 a 100 vem do banco de dados, crie uma coluna de nome disponivel do tipo ENUM('sim','não') de valor default sim. Dai quando quando o visitante submeter o formulario vc aproveita e faz um UPDATE nessa coluna para o valor não correspondente a coluna do respectivo numero. Para o proximo visitante carregue os numeros where coluna disponivel = sim